# Storing BLOB images in sql database for a SMALL website. - mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, blob

THere are many questions on stack overflow on whether storing images in a db is worth it for big websites and most poeple say no. I am making a very small website which will only potentially hold 20 images. I have spent alot of time setting up images to be uploaded to a database so would around 20 - 200 images - (around 10 - 50 KiB) slow down my website if I have the images stored on a database as a BLOB file.

I also likes the structure of a db as I can easily Add/Edit/Delete the images rather than going through the hassle of storing the images on a web server.

So basically is uploading 20-200 images that are around 10 - 50 KiB, will this slow down my website and how much slower would it get?

Answer (score 0):

The possible slow down depends on your environment. It should be negligible when your PHP implementation is right.

But the **browser caching** may really help you cut down the page load time. So, you will have to implement all the HTTP stuff related to the browser caching, e.g. HTTP HEAD, HTTP ETag, etc. Then, it's much easier to store the images as a local files, implement simple Add/Edit/Delete operations, and let the complicated caching stuff to the web server.